# WP plugin doesn't work on ajax loaded content

Tags: wordpress

I am using the plugin for share buttons. In my code, I am using it via shortcode function. All works perfectly, but these share buttons are not displayed on the ajax loaded content.

```
<div class="bottom-block flex align-center">
    <p class="post-date"><?php the_time('F j, Y g:i a'); ?></p>
    <p class="share-links"><?php echo do_shortcode('[do_widget id=ssba_widget-2]'); ?></p>
</div>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, you didn't include your code in the post

Comment: what is your plugin name?

Comment: also, looks like your shortcode written wrong

Comment: I am using Simple share buttons. But I tried other plugins and they work the same way.

Comment: add related ajax function and ajax request handler php function